# Is there a way to cummulate numbers within data frame in R

Tags: r, regex

Here is a sample dataframe and needed output shown below

DataFrame:

```
4699
2021845 
8.01834E+12 
4910 
4910 
7571 
7656 
3184 
8.01834E+12 
5871 
4437 
6321 
1779 
8.01834E+12 
2401
```

Output:

4-Digit numbers total - 11

Other numbers - 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nchar` to count number of digits.

```
four_count <- sum(nchar(df$V1) == 4)
cat(sprintf('4-Digit numbers total - %d\nOther numbers - %d', 
    four_count, nrow(df) - four_count))

#4-Digit numbers total - 11
#Other numbers - 4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(4699, 2021845, 8018340000000, 4910, 4910, 
7571, 7656, 3184, 8018340000000, 5871, 4437, 6321, 1779, 8018340000000, 
2401)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: thank you for above solution. I have DF with more than million rows, Is it possible to easily extract the values to check the result? so if I search for 4 digit count and I want to see all the values to confirm. Please let me know

Comment: `df$V1[nchar(df$V1) == 4]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `df` from [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62787518/7128934)

```
table((floor(log10(df)) + 1) == 4)

#FALSE  TRUE 
#    4    11
```

Comment: Thanks @d.b, I am getting this error, any pointers?

Comment: > head(newdf1)                      # view data frame
  originalCalledPartyNumber
1                      4699
2                   2021845
3             8018337934277
4                      4910
5                      4910
6                      7571
> table((floor(log10(newdf1)) + 1) == 4)
Error in Math.data.frame(newdf1) : 
  non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: originalCalledPartyNumber
>

Comment: > table((floor(log10(newdf1$originalCalledPartyNumber)) + 1) == 4)
Error in log10(newdf1$originalCalledPartyNumber) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>

Answer (score 0):

I have used `dim` and `nchar`. Uncomment `data.table` approach and comment out `dataframe` approach to see a frequency table of character count.

```
#library(data.table) # data.table approach

count_focus <- 4
dta <- data.frame(Numbers = c(
  4699, 2021845, 8.01834E+12, 4910, 4910, 7571, 7656, 3184, 
  8.01834E+12, 5871, 4437, 6321, 1779, 8.01834E+12, 2401))

dta$NumberOfCharacters <- nchar(dta$Numbers) # dataframe approach

message("4-Digit numbers total - ", dim(dta["NumberOfCharacters" == count_focus])[1]) # dataframe approach
message("Other numbers - ", dim(dta["NumberOfCharacters" != count_focus])[1]) # dataframe approach


#setDT(dta) # data.table approach
#dta[, NumberOfCharacters := nchar(Numbers)] # data.table approach


#message("4-Digit numbers total - ", dim(dta[NumberOfCharacters == count_focus])[1]) # data.table approach
#message("Other numbers - ", dim(dta[NumberOfCharacters != count_focus])[1]) # data.table approach
#dta[, .N, by = NumberOfCharacters] # data.table approach
```

Comment: getting the same result base on above,

Comment: > message("4-Digit numbers total - ", dim(dta["NumberOfCharacters" == count_focus])[1]) # dataframe approach
4-Digit numbers total - 15
> message("Other numbers - ", dim(dta["NumberOfCharacters" != count_focus])[1]) # dataframe approach
Other numbers - 15
>

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match string exactly 4 digits long by using position anchors `^`for string start position and `$`for string end position and subset `df`on those values that `grepl` looking for the matches returns as `TRUE`:

```
df[grepl("^\\d{4}$", df$V1), ]
[1] 4699 4910 4910 7571 7656 3184 5871 4437 6321 1779 2401
```